# Pic18F67K22 will not read program memory above 0x10000

Tags: pic18

I am writing a boot loader for Pic18F67K22 device. Program data 0x200- 0x1FFFF. Boot code resides in memory location <0x200 and is unaffected by boot load program update.  The program 0x200-0x1FFFF is getting proper values during programming and verified by reading device in IDE MPLAB8.92 with ICD3. When I run verify code the data from 0x200-0xFFFF is correct but once I get to 0x10000 all data reads back as 0x00. I also tested the device without the ICD3 and get the same result. I also tried compiling using a lookup table at 0rg 0x10000 to remove the boot load from the test and I get returned data 0x00. The program pointer is 21 byte wide for Low + high + upper and program memory is selected via EECON1,EEPGD & EECON1,CFGS. The TBLPTRU is correct at 0x01. I am reading the data from an external flash device. Any thoughts why its not reading ?

```
bt
 bcf INTCON,7 ;// disable ALL interrupts
 
 clrf EE_25LC_addr_L
 clrf EE_25LC_addr_H
 clrf EE_25LC_addr_U
 call Init_Read_Boot ;// Set the 25LC1024 Start read address
 

 movlw 0x00 ;// Set Start
 movwf TBLPTRL
 movwf File_byte_Counter_Low
 movlw 0x02
 movwf TBLPTRH
 movwf File_byte_Counter_High
 movlw 0x00
 movwf TBLPTRU
 movwf File_byte_Counter_Upper
 
Program_Loop 

 lfsr FSR0,0x500
 movlw .128
 movwf ByteCounter

 call ReadProgMem ;// Read block
 
 
 lfsr FSR0,0x400
 movlw .128
 movwf ByteCounter
 
 call Read_EEPROM ;// 0x400 Modify buffer with new data for write
 
 ;// Erase
 movf File_byte_Counter_Low,w
 movwf TBLPTRL ;// Set Start
 movf File_byte_Counter_High,w
 movwf TBLPTRH
 movf File_byte_Counter_Upper,w
 movwf TBLPTRU
 

 BSF EECON1, EEPGD ;//0x07 point to Flash program memory
 BCF EECON1, CFGS ;// 0x06 access Flash program memory
 BSF EECON1, WREN ;// 0x02 enable write to memory
 BSF EECON1, FREE ;// 0x04 ERASE (gets cleard on completion of Erase cycle)

 movlw 0x55 ; Erase block
 movwf EECON2
 movlw 0xAA
 movwf EECON2
 bsf EECON1, WR ;// 0x01 ; Start the write
 nop

 TBLRD*-

 ;// Write
 lfsr FSR0,0x400
 movlw .128
 movwf ByteCounter
 
 BSF EECON1, EEPGD ;//0x07 point to Flash program memory
 BCF EECON1, CFGS ;// 0x06 access Flash program memory
 BSF EECON1, WREN ;// 0x02 enable write to memory

 call WriteProgMem
 
 
 MOVLW 55h
 MOVWF EECON2 ; write 55h
 MOVLW 0AAh
 MOVWF EECON2 ; write 0AAh
 BSF EECON1, WR ; start program (CPU stall)

 movlw .128
 addwf File_byte_Counter_Low, F
 btfsc STATUS,C
 incf File_byte_Counter_High, F
 btfsc STATUS,C
 incf File_byte_Counter_Upper, F 
 
 
 btfss File_byte_Counter_Upper,1 ;// End of program space (U1)
 goto Program_Loop
 
 BCF EECON1, WREN ;// disable write to memory
 
  
 call delay_7ms
 nop
 banksel PORTA
 bsf LATA,3 ;// EPROM CS (SElECT)
 
 call delay_7ms
 
;// Add verification here

Jmp_V

 banksel EE_25LC_addr_L

 clrf EE_25LC_addr_L
 clrf EE_25LC_addr_H
 clrf EE_25LC_addr_U
 
 call Init_Read_Boot ;// Set the 25LC1024 Start read address
 
 movlw 0x00 ;// Set Start
 movwf File_byte_Counter_Low
 movlw 0x02
 movwf File_byte_Counter_High
 movlw 0x00
 movwf File_byte_Counter_Upper
 
  
Verify_Next_Block

 movf File_byte_Counter_Low,w ;// Set Start
 movwf TBLPTRL 
 movf File_byte_Counter_High,w
 movwf TBLPTRH
 movf File_byte_Counter_Upper,w
 movwf TBLPTRU
 
 movlw .128 
 movwf ByteCounter
 
Verify_Loop

 tblrd *+ ; Fill buffer

 movf TABLAT, w
 movwf CHK_Program_Byte
 

 movlw 0x00 ;// Read opcode
 movwf SSP2BUF
 btfss SSP2STAT,BF ;
 goto $-2
 

 movf SSP2BUF,w
 movwf CHK_Flash_Byte
 
 movf CHK_Program_Byte,w ;// CJNE
 subwf CHK_Flash_Byte,w
 btfss STATUS,Z
 call Exit_fail
 
 decfsz ByteCounter,f
 goto Verify_Loop
 
; bsf LATA,3 ;// EPROM CS (DISABLE SElECT)
 
 movlw .128
 addwf File_byte_Counter_Low, F
 btfsc STATUS,C
 incf File_byte_Counter_High, F
 btfsc STATUS,C
 incf File_byte_Counter_Upper, F 
 

 btfss File_byte_Counter_Upper,1 ;// End of program space
 goto Verify_Next_Block
```

Comment: Check Read Protection in Configuration Bits.

Comment: Config7L=0xFF not protected

Comment: What about CONFIG5?

Comment: config5L=0xFF, config5H=“11000000

Answer (score 0):

Before you are asking a question first make a simplified test program like this one.

```
;Read high FLASH bytes test   

#include "p18f87k22.inc"

; CONFIG1L
  CONFIG  RETEN = ON            ; VREG Sleep Enable bit (Enabled)
  CONFIG  INTOSCSEL = HIGH      ; LF-INTOSC Low-power Enable bit (LF-INTOSC in High-power mode during Sleep)
  CONFIG  SOSCSEL = HIGH        ; SOSC Power Selection and mode Configuration bits (High Power SOSC circuit selected)
  CONFIG  XINST = OFF           ; Extended Instruction Set (Disabled)
; CONFIG1H
  CONFIG  FOSC = INTIO2         ; Oscillator (Internal RC oscillator)
  CONFIG  PLLCFG = OFF          ; PLL x4 Enable bit (Disabled)
  CONFIG  FCMEN = OFF           ; Fail-Safe Clock Monitor (Disabled)
  CONFIG  IESO = OFF            ; Internal External Oscillator Switch Over Mode (Disabled)
; CONFIG2L
  CONFIG  PWRTEN = OFF          ; Power Up Timer (Disabled)
  CONFIG  BOREN = SBORDIS       ; Brown Out Detect (Enabled in hardware, SBOREN disabled)
  CONFIG  BORV = 3              ; Brown-out Reset Voltage bits (1.8V)
  CONFIG  BORPWR = ZPBORMV      ; BORMV Power level (ZPBORMV instead of BORMV is selected)
; CONFIG2H
  CONFIG  WDTEN = SWDTDIS       ; Watchdog Timer (WDT enabled in hardware; SWDTEN bit disabled)
  CONFIG  WDTPS = 1048576       ; Watchdog Postscaler (1:1048576) 
; CONFIG3L
  CONFIG  RTCOSC = SOSCREF      ; RTCC Clock Select (RTCC uses SOSC)
  CONFIG  EASHFT = ON           ; External Address Shift bit (Address Shifting enabled)
  CONFIG  ABW = MM              ; Address Bus Width Select bits (8-bit address bus)
  CONFIG  BW = 16               ; Data Bus Width (16-bit external bus mode)
  CONFIG  WAIT = OFF            ; External Bus Wait (Disabled)
; CONFIG3H
  CONFIG  CCP2MX = PORTC        ; CCP2 Mux (RC1)
  CONFIG  ECCPMX = PORTE        ; ECCP Mux (Enhanced CCP1/3 [P1B/P1C/P3B/P3C] muxed with RE6/RE5/RE4/RE3)
  CONFIG  MSSPMSK = MSK7        ; MSSP address masking (7 Bit address masking mode)
  CONFIG  MCLRE = ON            ; Master Clear Enable (MCLR Enabled, RG5 Disabled) 
; CONFIG4L
  CONFIG  STVREN = ON           ; Stack Overflow Reset (Enabled)
  CONFIG  BBSIZ = BB2K          ; Boot Block Size (2K word Boot Block size)
; CONFIG5L
  CONFIG  CP0 = OFF             ; Code Protect 00800-03FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  CP1 = OFF             ; Code Protect 04000-07FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  CP2 = OFF             ; Code Protect 08000-0BFFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  CP3 = OFF             ; Code Protect 0C000-0FFFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  CP4 = OFF             ; Code Protect 10000-13FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  CP5 = OFF             ; Code Protect 14000-17FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  CP6 = OFF             ; Code Protect 18000-1BFFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  CP7 = OFF             ; Code Protect 1C000-1FFFF (Disabled) 
; CONFIG5H
  CONFIG  CPB = OFF             ; Code Protect Boot (Disabled)
  CONFIG  CPD = OFF             ; Data EE Read Protect (Disabled)
; CONFIG6L
  CONFIG  WRT0 = OFF            ; Table Write Protect 00800-03FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  WRT1 = OFF            ; Table Write Protect 04000-07FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  WRT2 = OFF            ; Table Write Protect 08000-0BFFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  WRT3 = OFF            ; Table Write Protect 0C000-0FFFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  WRT4 = OFF            ; Table Write Protect 10000-13FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  WRT5 = OFF            ; Table Write Protect 14000-17FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  WRT6 = OFF            ; Table Write Protect 18000-1BFFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  WRT7 = OFF            ; Table Write Protect 1C000-1FFFF (Disabled)  
; CONFIG6H
  CONFIG  WRTC = OFF            ; Config. Write Protect (Disabled)
  CONFIG  WRTB = OFF            ; Table Write Protect Boot (Disabled)
  CONFIG  WRTD = OFF            ; Data EE Write Protect (Disabled)
; CONFIG7L
  CONFIG  EBRT0 = OFF           ; Table Read Protect 00800-03FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  EBRT1 = OFF           ; Table Read Protect 04000-07FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  EBRT2 = OFF           ; Table Read Protect 08000-0BFFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  EBRT3 = OFF           ; Table Read Protect 0C000-0FFFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  EBRT4 = OFF           ; Table Read Protect 10000-13FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  EBRT5 = OFF           ; Table Read Protect 14000-17FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  EBRT6 = OFF           ; Table Read Protect 18000-1BFFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  EBRT7 = OFF           ; Table Read Protect 1C000-1FFFF (Disabled)
; CONFIG7H
  CONFIG  EBRTB = OFF           ; Table Read Protect Boot (Disabled)
    
__RESET_CODE        code        0                       
    nop
    nop
    goto    ContinueCpuInitiation
;
__INTERRUPT_CODE    code        8
    retfie      1
    
ContinueCpuInitiation
    
    movlw   low Table0
    movwf   TBLPTRL
    movlw   high Table0    
    movwf   TBLPTRH
    movlw   upper Table0     
    movwf   TBLPTRU
;
    tblrd   *+              ; read into TABLAT and increment
    movf    TABLAT, W       ; get data from Table0 = 1
    tblrd   *+              ; read into TABLAT and increment
    movf    TABLAT, W       ; get data from Table0 =  2
    tblrd   *+              ; read into TABLAT and increment
    movf    TABLAT, W       ; get data from Table0 =  3

;... end test

    nop

__H         code        0x10000
Table0      
    db  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
    
    
    END
```

And test it in MPAB simulator, as you can see everything works fine...